# Joining tables with Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent

I am using the Eloquent library, and i want to join two tables and then display the result.

In my index.php i have the following lines:

```
$identification = $_GET['id'];
$schoolToArrangement = School::where('id', $identifikasjon)>with('arrangements')->get();
echo $skoleTilArrangement;
```

Ofcourse, i also have my School class:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

class School extends Model {
protected $fillable = [ 'id', 'name', 'adress', 'picture'];

public function arrangements()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Arrangement','schoolId','id');
}

}
```

And then, i ofcourse need an Arrangement class:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

class Arrangement extends Model {
   protected $fillable = [ 'id', 'schoolId', 'type', 'place', 'adress'];

}
```

So the idea is that im gonna make a page to display certain arrangements at certain schools.

But, when i echo $skole, the result is the following:

> [{"id":3,"navn":"Westerdals Campus
>
> Brenneriveien","adress":"Brenneriveien","picture":"https://www.westerdals.no/>content/uploads/2016/10/MH-brenneriveien-vulkan-oktober-26-1->960x720.jpg","arrangements":>{"id":1,"skoleId":3,"type":"Party","place":"Nightclub","adress":"Partyroad 1337"}}]

In other words my join is working.

However i would like to display only the row gathered from the Arrangements table, and not the corresponding row in the School table. Also, how can i echo the columns of the Arrangement table after joining?

Or in other words, how can i echo the information gathered from the Arrangements table?

Just ask if something is unclear, eventhough i think my issue should be understandable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So if you only want to output the arrangements of a school, you can do this:

`echo $skoleTilArrangement->arrangements`

and to itarate through arrangements:

```
foreach($skoleTilArrangement->arrangements as $arrangement) {
  echo $arrangment->id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! When i did "echo $skoleTilArrangement[0]->arrangements;", i was able to output the first arrangement. But excuse my 'noobieness' - how can i iterate through the array and display every arrangement?

Comment: I tried different variants of this without luck : 
    foreach ($skoleTilArrangement as &$skole) {
        echo $skoleTilArrangement->arrangementer->id;
    }